# Appending Character to String and return String

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to call in a `String`, add a character based on certain conditions, update the longest `String` and then return the `String`.

I know that since I'm changing the `String` (by adding characters), I can't use `const char* pointer`, thus I must use a `char array[]`.

But I also know that `char array[]` can't be returned, just the pointer. So I'm confused on how I can update a String (as a `char array[]`), and then return it (as a `const char* pointer`).

```
 const char* longestWord(char line[])
 {
     int pos = 0;
     char longest[250]; 
     char ch = line[pos];
     int longestLength = 0;
     char current[250];
     int currentLength = 0;

      if(isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch))
      {
          longest[longestLength] = ch;
          longest[longestLength + 1] = '\0';
          currentLength++;
      }

    pos++;  
 }
 return longest;
```

Comment: Does your compiler issue a warning on the `return longest` line?

Comment: Why don't you just pass it to the function as a pointer?

Comment: Choose between starting with a longer string in your source (so there is room for expansion), or allocating it and passing a *pointer* to the pointer (so it can be reallocated in the function).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, yes it does have a warning: `address of stack memory associated with local variable 'longest' returned`

Comment: @kris: Yeah, that means you're returning a local variable which when accessed from the outside, will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @rost0031 can I find out why the variable will result in undefined behavior?

Comment: `const char* longestWord(char line[])` <- note that this is equivalent to `const char* longestWord(char *line)` because of a (stupid) quirk of C syntax. You're already passing a pointer.

Comment: Because it's a variable that is only defined within the scope of the function.  When you return a pointer to an array only defined within the function, other functions may use that memory since it's no longer being used by that function.  Sometimes things will work, sometimes they won't.  IE: don't do this.
Look up "scope of variables in C" on google and read if you want more details than I'm giving here.

Comment: @kris: also, just so you know, your code only checks the first character of each new line every time you call this function.  I doubt that's what you are trying to actually accomplish.  What is your code supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the array to the function and you don't need to return anything:

```
void longestWord(char line[], char longest[])
                     //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless `line` is large enough to hold as much as it will ever need, you won't be able to do it this way.

Most straightforward solution here would be to have the argument be on the heap, so allocate it with `malloc(length_of_str)`. In `longestWord` you may then call `line = realloc(line, new_length)` in order to get yourself more room to stuff characters in.

Returning `longest` won't ever work as it is on the stack, which will be freed once your method is left. You may allocate `longest` via `malloc()` as well and return that pointer, in which case you'll only need to call `free()` on the returned pointer once you no longer need it.